# How to set Mocha to find my inner project modules?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, module, installation, mocha.js

My environment:

- Ubuntu v 16.04.6 LTS
- Node v8.17.0
- Webstorm 2019.3.3
- Mocha v. 7.1.0

Hi!

I am just starting on MOCHA.

I have this error when I run my test:

```
Error: cannot find the module: FirstModuleToIncludeByMyModuleToBeTested
```

where FirstModuleToIncludeByMyModuleToBeTested is a module that the unit I am testing uses. All modules that the unit that I am testing includes, have the same problem. This project is working fine on Node and on the webstorm, and both of them can find all libraries when is not working under Mocha.

I have installed MOCHA and I was already running isolated tests (not liked on the project). Everything fine so far until I tried to test an module on a real project. When I tried to run the tests, **mocha can find the module that I am testing**, but it **cannot** find the modules that this module is using (all of them are under the same project path) ... through the webstorm and through the command line I have the same problem, and get the same error message… All modules paths are relative to the root of the project folder, and the webstorm and nodeJs can run then ok when is not MOCHA.

I have tried several options on the webstorm regarding the work path for the project and for the mocha test… but nothing solves … I put the tests folder under the Project src folder. As well I tried to use the mocha test file on the same folder where there is the javascript module to be tested.

I have tried all Mocha intallations options like global and in the local project.

```
npm install --global mocha
```

This is the complete error message I get:

mymachine:$ mocha MyMochaTest.js

```
> Error: Cannot find module 'x/MyProject/Folder1/Folder2/
> FirstModuleToIncludeByMyModuleToBeTested'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/Desenv/Git/MyProjec/Folder3/Folder4/MyModuleToBeTested.js:1:80)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/Desenv/Git/MyProjec/MochaTests/MyMochaTest.js:4:23)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>     at /usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:314:36
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>     at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:311:14)
>     at /usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:347:12
>     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>     at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:346:12)
>     at singleRun (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:107:15)
>     at exports.runMocha (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:144:11)
>     at Object.exports.handler (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:306:11)
>     at Object.runCommand (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:242:26)
>     at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1087:28)
>     at Object.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:566:25)
>     at Object.exports.main (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/cli.js:68:6)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha:133:29)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
>     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
>     at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

On the command line, where the test was, inside the project path.

```
$ export NODE_PATH=<path to my project root>.
```